# Error Accessing Embedded Resource

Tags: java, audio, io, embedded-resource, filenotfoundexception

I'm making a program, and I want it to start playing sounds when it opens. I figured the easiest way for me to do this is to embed the .wav file in the src folder in my jar. I have placed the file in a packaged called `files` and all the other files i am using such as pictures are in that package and they all work fine. my method for playing sounds is here:

```
public static void playSound(String dir, int loopTimes) throws Exception {
    URL url = new File(dir).toURI().toURL();
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    // getAudioInputStream() also accepts a File or InputStream
    AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
    clip.open(ais);
    if (loopTimes == -1)
        loopTimes = Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY;
    clip.loop(loopTimes);
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

        }
    });
}
```

and it works for playing the sounds when they are on my desktop, my documents, anywhere else. the path that i am inputting for playing the sound is `"files/FBP.wav"` were FBP is the name of the file. i havent been able to find any solutions on google, and i have the feeling that it is because it is in the JAR. I have also just simply tried this:

```
if(new File("files/FBP.wav").exists()){
        System.out.println("EXISTS!");
    }
    System.exit(0);
```

and it never printed out that it exists. i have made sure that it is in the bin folder as well. i am using eclipse. the error i get is `filenotfoundexception`. any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
URL url = new File(dir).toURI().toURL();
```

With:

```
URL url = MySoundClassName.class.getClassLoader().getResource(dir);
```

Or for non-static methods:

```
URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(dir);
```

Comment: well sir, u are now proclaimed a wizard on all accounts. now do you know of a way to make it buffer the thing faster? there is a delay after running it because of the buffer. do you know how to shorten that? or is it required

Comment: @wbAnon instead of loading the clip every time the subroutine is executed, load it just once in a global variable, playing it every time it's called.

Comment: @wbAnon Well, if this method is going to be called over and over on the _same_ clip, why load it every time over and over. If it's a non-static variable, load it in constructor, if not, use the [static block](http://www.jusfortechies.com/java/core-java/static-blocks.php) to load it at class initialization, then you can play it how much you want.

Comment: ohhoh i see what you mean. alright then! thanks for the input and wizardry